# git randomly redownload all remote objects

Tags: git

in git after pull it downloads all objects present in history of remote repo from beginning like first checkout
No error is given
It's about 1hour of download
Case Study: 
UserA

```
git pull origin branch
remote: Counting objects: 23024, done.


<edits>
git add .
git commit -m "test1"
git push origin branch
```

UserB

```
git pull origin branch
remote: Counting objects: 23025, done.
<edits>
git add .
git commit -m "test1"
git push origin branch
```

UserA

```
git pull origin branch
remote: Counting objects: 250, done.
<edits>
git add .
git commit -m "test1"
git push origin branch
```

at this point UserB on pull, git redownload again all objects present on remote repository
UserB

```
git pull origin branch
remote: Counting objects: 24125, done.
Receiving objects: 100% (24125/24125), 1007.93 MiB | 1.17 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (15457/15457), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (5307/5307), done.
```

Comment: It's not clear from your snippets what's going on.  Can you actually include git's output, too?

Comment: sorry, i just edit my post

Comment: Aha.  _Counting Objects_ is not _Downloading_.  It's something done on the server side to determine what you need.  Who or what is hosting your Git repository?

Comment: edward git download again about 200 MB

Comment: Git should tell you what it downloaded.  Can you post that information?

Comment: edward i have updated the post with new info

Comment: Hand-edited logs that omit crucial details are not helpful. There's more happening than you're showing.  This isn't a puzzle site. Show what actually happened, what you actually did, what it actually said.  So far you've twice added incrementally more detail and somehow managed to avoid showing the details that produced the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Does this really happen randomly on everybody's workspaces, or is it confined to one user, or perhaps even one repository on one user's PC?

Comment: jthill this happening randomly and its impossible to copy-paste because its happen before i open this post and since that date it didn't happen again. I tried to update my post to explain better what is the problem, yes i wrote some random numbers but its just to make it more clear. The problem is that after push when userB pull git spent hours downloading the entire project. To Mort, this happen with any user but only on one branch (for now)

Answer (score 0):

Its not randomly.
it how git works.

When you add code to git (`git commit`) it will be downloaded next time.

**User A**

```
# Download latest version
git pull origin branch
<edits>
git add .
git commit -m "test1"

# New changes are send to server
git push origin branch
```

**User B**

```
# Download all changes user A added to git
git pull origin branch
<edits>
git add .
git commit -m "test1"

# Push new changes to server 
git push origin branch
```

***Note***: At this point user A does not not have those changes yet, he will grab them on the next pull.

**User A**

```
# Now user A gets the updates form the server
git pull origin branch
<edits>
git add .
git commit -m "test1"

# Again - send updates to the server
git push origin branch
```

> At this point UserB on pull, git redownload again all objects present on remote repository

As explained above - user A added new content to the remote repo which is not yet found on user B repository as on the next pull the content will be downloaded again (only the delta from last pull)

Comment: UserB will download just some objects that don't have not ALL the objects prensent in the history of repository doing everytime a 1h of download

Comment: I dont understand you, what you trying to say that it download for 1 hour?

Comment: the number of objects to download isnt 500 or 50 but 50.000 or 80.000, same number of objects to download if i checkout the project on empty folder

Comment: That's why- you are downloading the repository from scratch every time as you mentioned above,

Comment: @CodeWizard that doesn't make sense to me. I work with huge repositories and I can assure you that the git client and server on `fetch` exchange information about what the client has and the server only bundles up what the client is missing, only the latest commits.

Comment: i am not downloading it, just using pull command to get the new changes. Instead of download just the new updates, git download the entire history of changes

Comment: i just edit my post , i hope its more clear what is the problem